# cp from string as source destination

Tags: shell, cp

I have a shell variable $allpath with the value

```
"/opt/in1/InputFile1.csv  /opt/InputFile2.csv"
```

means , when I do echo, I get the above string.

Now I try to do the following:

```
cp "$allpath" /opt/targetdir
```

and I get error:

> cp: cannot stat ‘ /opt/in1/InputFile1.csv /opt/in2/InputFile2.csv’: No such file or directory

but when I manually type in

```
cp /opt/in1/InputFile1.csv  /opt/InputFile2.csv  /opt/targetdir
```

it does the copy
so how can I do it with the shell variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes are making the shell interpret it as one file, which obviously doesn't exist. Drop them, and you should be fine:

```
cp $allpath /opt/targetdir
```

Comment: Right until you hit a filename with whitespace and/or a `cp` argument in it.

Comment: would this also work with sshpass scp instead of cp?

Comment: @sakal yes, it should.

Answer (score 0):

In shells that support arrays, use them.

```
allpath=("/opt/in1/InputFile1.csv" "/opt/InputFile2.csv")
cp "${allpath[@]}" /opt/targetdir
```

Comment: This is a feature of the shell, not the executable.